# Firebase function log not displaying data

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, firebase, logging

[Here is a screenshot of my firebase console, notice how it is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8Org.png)
I have recently added Firebase to my project and have made sure that the firebase modules I want are already installed in my `functions` folder. I have the following code in my `index.js` file:

```
 const functions = require('firebase-functions');
 const admin = require('firebase-admin');
 admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
 // // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
 // // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-       functions
 //
  exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 response.send("Hello from Fire!");
 console.log('I am a log entry!')
});
```

I have followed the Firebase Cloud Functions tutorial video step for step and from my understanding the string `I am a log entry!` should be displaying in my firebase console under the logs tab along with the name of the deployed function. However it remains empty and neither the function or the log data shows. I was wondering why this was. Is my code incorrect? All help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess is that you have not successfully deployed your revised code. Try deploying again and look for `functions[helloWorld]: Successful update operation` in the deploy log. You should also move `response.send(...)` to the end of your function, _after_ `console.log(...)`.

Comment: I removed the `response.send(...)` , deployed, and my function does still not show up in the console on firebase.

Answer (score -2):

You need to execute following commands in your functions directory to make sure it has been deployed:

- firebase login
- firebase init functions
- npm install
  *and then:*
- firebase deploy --only functions

If deployment failed, you should see this wiyhin the logs provided by last command